# How to use DYNAMIC two bone IK Constraint on Unreal 4 via HoloLens 2

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, inverse-kinematics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTKUR.png)

Hello,
i am trying to use two bone ik constraint on the arms of my 3d model. my aim is, via hololens, the user can touch the model^s arm and move it up or down. for this i think two bone ik contraint is needed. in the screenshot i can manipulate my model in the left side by moving the effector. i need the effector to be interactable via hololens to make it work. i dont know how to do that. i added mrtk and uxtools (i can manipulate a cube and stuff via hololens) can anyone help me- i dont know anything about unreal and i need to know how, i only could find stuff about animation but my situtation isnt an animation, its a dynamic thing.

thanks

Comment: guys... anyonee? i really need to do this and there is no such video on this ;(

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can add Manipulator Components to Actor to achieve interaction, you can refer to [Manipulator Component | UXT Documentation (microsoft.github.io)](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-UXTools-Unreal/Docs/Manipulator.html). Also, for beginners, this tutorial may be useful to you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch1.

Comment: i know uxtgenericmanipulator. it work for graabbing and dragging stuff. but my problem is i have a 3d character and its in tpose. i can move it around in tpose of course, but i cant to grab its arms and move it up and down. that is the problem.